# find by property name in JPA repository returns the value of first row alone

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am new to spring boot and  was trying to implement an sales related application. There i implemented a custom findBy method using property name customer id . The following is the output i am getting

```
[{"customerId":101,"stockId":1},{"customerId":101,"stockId":1},{"customerId":101,"stockId":1},{"customerId":101,"stockId":1}]
```

which is actually the first row but the values in table is different.

```
CUSTOMER_ID     STOCK_ID  
101              1
101              2
101              3
101              4
102              1
103              2
103              3
104              4
```

Since it is a sample start up application i didnt specify any constraints. what i am doing wrong here.

**Update:**

this is my Repository

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerSalesRepo extends JpaRepository<CustomerSales,Integer> {

    public List<CustomerSales> findAllByCustomerId(int custID);
}
```

this is my sales entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = CustomerSales.TABLE_NAME)
public class CustomerSales {
    
    public static final String TABLE_NAME= "CUSTOMER_SALES";
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    private int customerId;
    
    @Column
    private int stockId;
```

data.sql

```
DROP TABLE CUSTOMER_SALES IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_SALES (customer_Id INT, stock_Id INT);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMERSALES (customer_Id,stock_Id)VALUES (101,1),(101,2),(101,3),(101,4),(102,1),(103,2),(103,3),(104,4);
```

Comment: please add the method you used in the JAP interface

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: `CustomerSales` has `customerId`  Primary Key . But You are listing records with dup primary keys (4 records with 101, 2 with 103). I dont think you are posting your actual DB schema or code. If you are using mysql/postgres etc can you execute `show create table CUSTOMER_SALES ;` and show the results here?

Comment: Its because i didn't define any constraints which is in sql statement i didn't mention it as primary key . When i defined it thrown error as duplicate values for primary key. The concept is here is a customer can any number of stocks which is he can take stock 1 , 2 , 3, 4 .. i cant store it in stock table since a stock can be associated to any number of customers.  How do you specify relationship among entities..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you were able to populate that data set into your DB table since there is a primary key on `customerId` only. That means that you cannot have more than 1 row with `CUSTOMER_ID = 101`.

You should define a composite PK class

```java
public class CustomerSalesPk implements Serializable
{
    private int customerId;
    private int stockId;

    public int getCustomerId()
    {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(final int customerId)
    {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public int getStockId()
    {
        return stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(final int stockId)
    {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }
        
}
```

Then use this PK class in your entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = CustomerSales.TABLE_NAME)
@IdClass(CustomerSalesPk.class)
public class CustomerSales
{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "CUSTOMER_SALES";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private int customerId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID")
    private int stockId;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But it didnt work for me. i am getting the following output [{"customerId":0,"stockId":null}]

Comment: @ani please try adding the column name `@Column(name = "STOCK_ID")` to `CustomerSales.stockId` as my updated example. This should help properly map the column.

Comment: For the above solution, you would have to declare the composite primary key in your `data.sql`.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. I am not able to insert the sample data as you can see there are duplicate values. The customer id is repeated here just to implicate that a customer can have any number of stocks and a stock can be sold to any number of customers. can you help me how to achieve this relationship

Comment: I think if you simply follow my code sample and do not create the table yourself, but rather let Hibernate generate it for you it will work. The composite PK will be generated by Hibernate and it should work.